# Full page background image with vertical scrolling

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create a page where the background image is responsive to your browser's screen size. However, I need content under that image such that if the person scrolls down, the background image ends.

It's hard to explain so I've tried to create an image to make it clearer:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/Z1mSMVi.png]

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/how-to-get-web-page-size-browser-window-size-screen-size-in-a-cross-browser-wa

Comment: I've tried making the responsive background image with no avail. I wasn't able to figure it out.

Comment: @bjan Any way to do it with CSS?

Comment: http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag/     https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwt64/281/):

HTML:

```
<div class='image'></div>
<div class='content'>Content</div>
```

Use absolute positioning to make the background image the same size as the screen, and put the content after, with a `top` of `100%`:

```
body { 
    margin:0;
}
.image {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%; 
    height:100%; 
    background:green;
    background-image:url('some-image.jpg');
    background-size:cover;
}
.content {
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; 
    top:100%; 
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Any way to make the 'content' class outside of the 'image' class?

Comment: you can simply make two different div. first <div class='image'></div> and then <div class='content'>Content</div>. Same css would work for you.

Comment: This is overkill. There is no need for `position:absolute` on anything. See my answer

Answer (score 4):

There is no need for `position: absolute` as tb11 suggests.

You can simply set the height of the viewport using viewport units or by setting the height for the html, body, and image elements.

Using `vh` - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwt64/281/) and [support chart](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units):

```
body { margin: 0; }
.image {
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh; 
    background: green;
    background-image: url('some-image.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```

---

If you can't use `vh`, you'll have to set the height of the html and body elements as well so that you can use percents - [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwt64/282/):

```
html, body, .image { height: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; }
.image {
    width:100%;
    background: green;
    background-image: url('some-image.jpg');
    background-size: cover;
}
```