# Responsive fullscreen image with scroll

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make so that when the user visits my site to see only one image (100% width) and when he scrolls down to be able to view the rest of the site.

I've seen this and tried it...it works: [Full page background image with vertical scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18050611/full-page-background-image-with-vertical-scrolling)

But i have two main concerns:

1. By this method i must use position: absolute for every section below the image (I will have at least different 4-5 sections with content). Is that the right thing to do ?
2. This method does not seem to be responsive, is there a way to make it ?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://www.flickr.com/new/)?

Comment: yes, but the width and height must be 100%

Comment: Have you tried `html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; }`? Then on each section you just include something liek this, `.myDiv { width: 100%; height: 100% }` and it will be the entire view-port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use position at all. Once you set a div's size with the screen size all the rest of your content will be below.

Here you go: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/nkkAy/2/)

The `image` div will contain your image, and you set it to `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`

then, just add your content below this div.

HTML:

```
<div class='image'>
    <img src="image.jpg" />
</div>
<div class='content'>Content</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

.image{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background: green;
}

.image img{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

.content {
    width:100%; height: 100px;
}
```

You also need to add

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

to support all screen sizes.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it and it works in general. The problem is that the image becomes a little bigger that the screen and a scrollbar is displayed and I don't want that. Is there a way to remove it?

Comment: have you tried `overflow: hidden` in the img css? Anyway, in this structure it shouldn't happen. did you set your padding and margin to 0? did you set the img border to 0?

Comment: Got it, the problem comes because the div class="image" is in section(this tag does not have any styling) tag in my code. When i remove the section the scrollbar disappears, but I don't know why does this problem comes in the first place. The overflow: hidden; does not seem to work, and the margin, padding and borders are 0

Comment: I just added height: 100%; to the section tag and it works fine now. Thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/stddC/

In this way the image will be 100% `height` and `width` and won't mess with the content.